# How do I make my apk file android unity3d compatible with all android devices on google play

Tags: google-play-services, google-play-games

My apk file Supported devices only 12869 . Is their any way I can get more like 400,000 devices something like that. I am only doing this for android devices on google play.

Answer (score 1):

The distibution of the versions of Android are reported on the [Android Dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html).  The Minimum API Level property in the Android Player Settings in the Unity Editor should be set to the lowest possible API level that your application needs.

For example, if you set the API Level to Android 5.1 (Lollipop) (API Level 22), you will only be targeting devices running Lollipop or newer which is about 40% of devices.  However, if you set the min level to Android 3.0 (Honeycomb) (API Level 11) you'll be compatible with over 98% of all the devices.